# If $ E \rightarrow X $ is a covering, then $ |\pi_1 (X)|$ divides to $ \chi (E) $

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I want to prove that no finite group acts free in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ in the process I found the following doubt:

> How can you prove that: If $ E \rightarrow X $ is a covering, then $ |\pi_1 (X)|$ divides to $ \chi (E) $?

Comment: The correct statement is if $E\to X$ is an $n$-sheeted covering then $\chi(E)=n\chi(X)$. One proof is by lifting a triangulation of $X$ to $E$ over the covering map. Note that every triangle has $n$ lifts, thus $\chi(E)=n\chi(X)$, since the lifted triangles triangulate $E$. If $E$ is simply connected (thus the universal cover), then $E$ has $|\pi_1(X)|$ sheets.